# countrycode() doesn't recognize iso2n which it should

Tags: r

I'm using `countrycode` 1.1.1 library for R and according to it's documentation, iso2n should be recognized both as origin and destination. Still, this happens to me:

```
    > countries_char <- countrycode(countries, origin = 'iso2n', destination 
    =  'iso2c')
    *Error in countrycode(countries, origin = "iso2n", destination = "iso2c"): 
    Origin code not supported by countrycode or present in the user-supplied 
     custom_dict.*
```

'countries' is just a character vector. Is it a bug?

Comment: It would be better to report issues with a particular package to the issue page for that package: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode/issues

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks!